# Declined comment flag again. Why?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, declined-flags

I recently asked a question [Who are these women mentioned in the Hiranyakeshin Grihya sutras?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31586/5212)

I thought the verse which I posted is from Shukla Yajurveda. But [a comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31586/who-are-these-women-mentioned-in-the-hiranyakeshin-grihya-sutras#comment94646_31586) came from a moderator that the translation of the verse from Yajurveda is different and posted a link to translation.

> Translation is completely different here archive.org/details/yajurvedacomplete/page/n27

After looking at the comment, I have realized that I posted a wrong verse and then edited out the question completely locating the verse from Hiranya Keshin Grihya sutras. I also replied to the moderator that I will look into it again and edited the question properly.  I edited tags, title and the body to suit the corrected flag.

After this revision, the comment which gives translation from Shukla Yajurveda is outdated and no longer valid. Because the question has nothing to do with Shukla Yajurveda but it is about Grihya sutras. The comment flag description reads

> **This comment is outdated**, conversational or **not relevant to this post**.

You may check the [revisions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/31586/revisions) of the questions and [timeline](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/31586/timeline) of the question.

So I flagged this comment as "It's no longer needed" because it is outdated and misleading for users (it already had an upvote) 15 hours ago.

I want to know what caused the decline of the comment flag from the moderator who handled the flag. How is the comment still relevant with current revision when the link is to other scripture than what I asked about?

Comment: I deleted the comment. Actually i thought the translation of that Shukla yajurveda verse was same as Rigveda verse when i skimmed the Yajurveda Sanskrit verses at that night. But later checked and found verses of Yajurveda are different.